# How to write a loop of command line to run asynchronously in python

Tags: python, linux, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write a series of linux command to run asynchronously in python, i can print out the linux command, but when I try to asyncio.run then it keep throwing error, does anyone know what Im doing wrong?

````
import asyncio
import subprocess

def get_args():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Run bulk generator in Gen server')

    parser.add_argument('--number_of_intercept', default='200',
                help='Number of intercept going into MSOM')

    return parser.parse_args()

async def bulk_generator (get_args):
    outputlist = []

    generator = "/bin/generator/./Generator.exe --direth -w 0000:84:00.1 -- -c 500 -d 62,598,62,1500,62 -r 500 -g eth+vlan:vlan_stream-id="+str(get_args)+"+vlan:vlan_stream-id="+str(get_args)+",span_number_vlan_ids=1+binseqn stream-id=100,eth_src=11:22:33:44:55:66"
    print(generator)
    p = subprocess.Popen([generator], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = str(p.communicate())
    outputlist.append(output)
    return outputlist


if __name__ == "__main__":

    args = get_args()
    for i in range(1,int(args.number_of_intercept)):
      asyncio.run(bulk_generator(i))


**********************Output******************************
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jasonleung/generator.py", line 32, in <module>
    asyncio.run(bulk_generator(i))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/jasonleung/generator.py", line 22, in bulk_generator
    p = subprocess.Popen([generator], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1845, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/bin/generator/./Generator.exe --direth -w 0000:84:00.1 -- -c 500 -d 62,598,62,1500,62 -r 500 -g eth+vlan:vlan_stream-id=1+vlan:vlan_stream-id=1,span_number_vlan_ids=1+binseqn stream-id=100,eth_src=11:22:33:44:55:66'

Process finished with exit code 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

When the command argument to `subprocess.Popen()` is a list, the command and arguments must be separate list elements. You put the entire command line in the first list element, so it thinks that's the name of the command. `generator` should be a list, then you don't need to wrap it in another list.

```
async def bulk_generator (get_args):
    outputlist = []

    generator = ["/bin/generator/./Generator.exe", "--direth", "-w", "0000:84:00.1", "--", "-c", "500", "-d", "62,598,62,1500,62", "-r", "500", "-g", f"eth+vlan:vlan_stream-id={get_args}+vlan:vlan_stream-id={get_args},span_number_vlan_ids=1+binseqn", "stream-id=100,eth_src=11:22:33:44:55:66"]
    print(generator)
    p = subprocess.Popen(generator, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = str(p.communicate())
    outputlist.append(output)
    return outputlist
```

Answer (score 0):

it’s because you’re passing the whole command with it’s arguments. Only include the executable as the first argument than have the second parameter be a list of all the arguments you want to pass for the executable